# How to convert a non-delimited strings like MMDDYYYY to MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a generic function to convert user input in well formated date string like `DD-MM-YYYY`.

For example -

I have a string `27031990` I want to convert this into `27-03-1990`. Similarly, if user has put in `2731990` it should get converted into `27-03-1990`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "_no matter what user has put in_" Not possible, there's no way to separate all DDM and DMM values correctly.

Comment: @str I mean the user can put in any format listed above. We need to format in DD-MM-YYYY format on blur.

Comment: Make consecutive checks to find out which format is used and split it into its components with an appropriate regular expression.

Comment: @Daniel updated the fiddle I tried. No success though

Comment: @NiteshGoyal This is not possible. What is 1112000? January or November?

Comment: @Str Yes you are right. Didn't notice that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a regular expression to split the date into it's components.

[`/^(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4}|\d{2})$/gm`](https://regexr.com/3t4b9)

Example usage:

```
const datePattern = /^(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4}|\d{2})$/gm;
const date = '2-12-18';

let [, day, month, year] = datePattern.exec(date);
```

Here's a function you can use for padding the a string with an arbitrary number of zeroes:

```
function zeroPad(string, digits) {
    const zeros = Array(digits).fill('0');
    return (zeros + string).slice(-digits);
}
```

So you'd use this as

```
date = zeroPad(day);
month = zeroPad(month);
```

And then you could use a conditional for converting years in `YY` format to `YYYY` perhaps using the `19` prefix if the `year` is greater `18` or `20` otherwise. Just an example, but hopefully you get what I mean.

**Edit 1**: As @Daniel suggested, you could use ES2017's [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) rather than using the ad-hoc `zeroPad` function.

**Edit 2**: If you want it to work with non-delimited strings, the date will have to be either in `DDMMYY` format or in `DDMMYYYY` to avoid ambiguity as @Teemu pointed out in the comments to your question. You could implement this is in regex as [`/^(\d{2})[\/\-]?(\d{2})[\/\-]?(\d{4}|\d{2})$/gm`](https://regexr.com/3t4c7)

**Edit 3**: @CertainPerformance suggested destructuring the matches immediately. I've incorporated this.

Comment: Thanks @shreyasminocha!!  This works for me.

Comment: Just an idea, destructuring the match immediately might be a bit more elegant.

Comment: Great!! Thanks @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 2):

Take the input and split it by either `/` delimiter or `-` delimiter by using a regex seperator:

```
.split(/[\/-]/);
```

Then map the result using the ES2017 function `padStart()` so that 0's are prepended if neccesary

```
.padStart(2, "0")
```

Finally, join the array with the dash symbol (`-`) and you should have your result.

#### Example

```js
let input = "27/03/1990";
let result = input.split(/[\/-]/).map(i => i.padStart(2, "0")).join('-');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Despite your answer was great, couldn't help me actually as this will not resolve the condition where user enter - 2731990.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can extract the in index of non numeric charachter and call subString() function till that for initial array index. Then use the same for month and year till you reach the end of the string.